# Right-aligned PS1 and PS1 equals itself?

Tags: bash, prompt

read some code somewhere about right alignment of text and have some questions:

```
        PS1="`printf "%${COLUMNS}s\n" "${TEXT}"`$PS1"
```

1. what are the backticks doing?
2. why is there another PS1 at the end of the line?

Thanks for your input:)

Answer (score 0):

That creates a prompt where you have the right-justified `$TEXT`, followed by a newline, followed by the previous value of `$PS1`.

The backticks are the shell's [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution): the shell will execute the command and substitute the command's output.
It's generally recommended to use the `$(cmd)` syntax instead of the `` `cmd` `` syntax.

That line can be written without command substitution, using the `printf -v varname` syntax:

```bsh
printf -v PS1 '%*s\n%s' "$COLUMNS" "$TEXT" "$PS1"
```

Comment: so, in the previous value of $PS1 I could put the left main left prompt so that both prompts would be on the same line?

Comment: No, you're explicitly adding a newline, so they're not on the same line. I don't know how to correctly set up a right prompt on the same line.